# CheckedListBox Repopulating problem in C#.NET

Tags: c#, windows

I have populate a CheckedListBox binding a DataSource with Display Member and Vlaue Member.
I have saved the values of the checkedValues in Database with a Relational Table.
I need to repopulate the checkedListbox getting the checked which value was checked(Saved) previously.I have done the First step. But in the Second step i am unable to get the index of the items to keep them checked comparing the relational table.

Following my code to bind the CheckedListBox:

```
private void FillCheckedListBox (CheckedListBox chkListBox, string sSql, string displayMember, string valueMember)
        {
            try {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DaoCodeGCommon.GetConstring());
                con.Open();
                DataTable accTable = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, con);
                SqlDataAdapter adpObj = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                accTable.TableName = "tbl";
                adpObj.Fill(accTable);
                con.Close();
                chkListBox.DataSource = accTable;
                chkListBox.ValueMember = valueMember;
                chkListBox.DisplayMember = displayMember;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to repopulate the checkedListBox?

Comment: "I request to mail me to giving the solution at jajaboor@gmail.com Thanks in advance. I" - why so if this issue occurs to someone else on this forum they won't know how to fix the issue because someone mailed you a solution?  Don't tell people you need the solution via email.  If there is a solution it should be posted on here.

Comment: @Farazi: I'm leaving @JonH's comment in place as an explanation for my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the status in the database and you are pulling the data from the db you can easily reload the check box list.

For instance assume you load a check box list with some sort of reader:

```
chkUsers.DataSource = reader;
chkUsers.DataTextField = "YourTextFieldToView";
chkUsers.DataValueField = "YourValueFieldToHide";
chkUsers.DataBind();
```

So now you've loaded the check list box, and now you need to turn the check boxes on / off.

```
for(int i =0; i< chkUsers.Items.Count-1; i++)
 {
  if(dbVal == chkUsers.Items(i).Value)
   {
    chkUsers.Items(i).Selected = dbVal;
   }
  }
```

In this case dbVal may be some value in a reader or dataset or datatable etc.